# Transaction linked SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am using SQL Server, I have some linked server for OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

I want to insert data to the linked server using transaction.

When I do it, I get this error:

> The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "L_10_2017_Ari1" does not
>   support the required transaction interface.

I tried to change the `msdtc` but it's not helping.

I am using access db

Comment: And it cannot if your linked server is an excel file. Backup - reconsider your approach. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am using access db                                                                                                   i try insert data to more of one table with transaction

Comment: Although Access supports transactions, I'm fairly sure it does not support distributed transactions ("distributed" here does not merely mean across servers, it also means across instances of different database systems). MSDTC won't fix that, since the underlying provider still needs to support them. You probably have to ask yourself how committed you are to having everything happen in one transaction -- for example, you could manually undo changes if it turns out the Access inserts failed, or write changes to a Service Broker queue to process in Access later.

Comment: can you give me any example how use Service Broker queue to process in Access later? thank you!

Comment: That would exceed the scope of an answer, let alone a comment. There are Service Broker tutorials online; the basics would be that you send the rows (or possibly just the IDs or a range) as a message in a Service Broker conversation. You can then use internal activation (with a stored procedure) to process these messages and produce the inserts into Access.